# Spring JPA using @MappedSuperclass joins the wrong entity type in QueryUtils when requesting Pageable w/ Sort

Tags: spring, jpa

**Context:**

In Kotlin, I have entity classes that are versioned, so there's the general entity class "EntityA" and the entity "EntityAVersion".

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_a")
class EntityA(

//single instanceCount field

) : VersionedEntity<EntityA, EntityAVersion>()
```

as well the versioned entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_a_version")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class EntityAVersion(
    
    //Many columns unique to this entity A

) : EntityVersion<EntityAVersion, EntityA>()
```

Imagine that there are pairs of these for B, C...G as well.

The `VersionedEntity` class, from which `EntityA` inherits, joins `EntityA` with `EntityAVersion`

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class VersionedEntity<Self : VersionedEntity<Self, V>, V : EntityVersion<V, Self>>(
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "current_version_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    var latest: V? = null,

    //other stuff
) : BaseEntity()
```

**The Problem:**

The ORM works fine for all the basic CRUD stuff until trying to make a request using a Pageable that contains a Sort for one of fields in EntityA.latest.someField. As JPA, inside its `QueryUtils` class, walks down the path of `EntityA` to `latest` to `someField`, it establishes how the entities join together.

However, *it incorrectly decides that the type of* `latest` *is EntityAVersion, regardless of what it should be (B, C, D, etc.)*.

From inside `QueryUtils` in **JPA 2.6.10**

```
private static boolean requiresOuterJoin(From<?, ?> from, PropertyPath property, boolean isForSelection,
            boolean hasRequiredOuterJoin) {

        String segment = property.getSegment(); //at this point, segment is "latest"

        ...

        Bindable<?> propertyPathModel;
        Bindable<?> model = from.getModel();

        ManagedType<?> managedType = null;
        if (model instanceof ManagedType) {
            managedType = (ManagedType<?>) model;
        } else if (model instanceof SingularAttribute
                && ((SingularAttribute<?, ?>) model).getType() instanceof ManagedType) {
            managedType = (ManagedType<?>) ((SingularAttribute<?, ?>) model).getType();
        }
        if (managedType != null) {

            //HERE IS THE PROBLEM: "getAttribute(segment)" only ever returns "EntityAVersion"
            propertyPathModel = (Bindable<?>) managedType.getAttribute(segment);
        } else {
            propertyPathModel = from.get(segment).getModel();
        }
...
}
```

in the last `if` block, `propertyPathModel = (Bindable<?>) managedType.getAttribute(segment);` is where it goes awry. Stepping into "getAttribute()" brings us into the `AbstractManagedType` class
from **Hibernate-core:5.6.15.Final**:

```
public PersistentAttributeDescriptor<? super J, ?> getAttribute(String name) {
        PersistentAttributeDescriptor<? super J, ?> attribute = (PersistentAttributeDescriptor)this.declaredAttributes.get(name);
        if (attribute == null && this.getSuperType() != null) {
            attribute = this.getSuperType().getAttribute(name);
        }

        this.checkNotNull("Attribute ", attribute, name);
        return attribute;
    }
```

The line `this.getSuperType().getAttribute(name)` (where name is "latest") seemingly hopelessly only ever returns a `SingularAttributeImpl` of type `EntityVersionA`, irrespective of the "path" beginning with a different entity, e.g. "EntityB.latest.someFieldUniqueToB".

The consequence of it being the wrong type of Bindable is that it only ever left joins to EntityVersionA, which causes JPA to bungle the sorting (the field unique to EntityVersionB, for instance, would never be found) and a stacktrace about not finding that property is printed.

Is there something that should change about the ORM that can fix this?

Comment: Your query is difficult to read as we cannot tell what ? is mapping to - maybe make a more concrete example to show the issue. EntityA only ever references an EntityVersionA correct? How are you getting the managedType and what is its type? JPA does not support querying on a mappedSuperclass(your VersionedEntity) so you are likely forcing it to be an EntityA instance somewhere.

Comment: It isn't a query, it is JPA's QueryUtils class that's featuring the "?". When querying results, say, a single EntityA, the content of the result includes a property "latest" which is of type EntityVersionA. The MappedSuperclass is not queried. The issue is that JPA itself can't properly disambiguate between EntityA.latest, EntityB.latest, etc. from within QueryUtils. This problem only seems to become relevant as a consequence of using a Pageable with a Sort.

Comment: The actual cause of this problem seems to be that a class within hibernate-core called "AbstractManagedType" populates a hashmap of "declaredAttributes" when the application starts. Because all my EntityVersionA, EntityVersionB, etc. have a "latest" field inherited from VersionedEntity, there's nothing but collision in declaredAttributes, as it stores entries of String->SingularAttributeImpl, where the string is always "latest". It seems other CRUD operations don't rely on this mechanism, but Pageable's "Sort" does...

Comment: Show the query, not hibernate internals (and QueryUtils is hibernate code, not JPA) - EntityA is not interchangeable with EntityB, so I would expect this problem occurring on more than just sorting by this field. From what you've shown, I'd file a bug. As mentioned, you might try making VersionedEntity a JPA entity using table per class for inheritance. Otherwise, I'd guess you have to move the latest mapping into the subclasses - hopefully hibernate savvy users can come up with better options.